# How to print an API doc for kotlin data classes with @SerializedName annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to create a document with a list of kotlin data classes that contain `@SerializedName("propertyName")` fields.

Ideally it would be some retrofit plugin that will output endpoints with the object types I expect. Is there a plugin to do this easily and if not how would I go about producing this kind of output?